# Add white line to align environment

Tags: equations, alignment, white-space

I want to add a white line in between the two equations of the code below. Everything I tried resulted in the white line being listed as an additional equation.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
{}&\int_{-T}^{T} a_n \cos{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}dt=\frac{a_nT}{n\pi}\cdot- 
\sin{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}\rvert_{-T}^T=\\
%
&-\frac{a_nT}{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\sin{(n\pi)}-\sin{(-n\pi)}\rbrack=\frac{a_nT} 
{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack0-0\rbrack=0
\end{split}\\
%I'd like a white line here, separating the two equations more clearly. It needs to be exactly the size of 1 normal white space.
\begin{split}
{}&\int_{-T}^{T} b_n \sin{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)} dt=\frac{b_nT} 
{n\pi}\cdot\cos{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}\rvert_{-T}^T=\\
%
&\frac{b_nT}{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\cos{(n\pi)}-\cos{(-n\pi)}\rbrack=\frac{b_nT} 
{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\cos{(n\pi)}-\cos{(n\pi)}\rbrack=0
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Well, you could just put `\\[4ex]` after the first `\end{split}`. This adds vertical whitespace.

Comment: @campa This doesn't work because the line \\[4ex] is listed as a new equation.

Comment: The intended suggestion by @campa must have been to add `[4ex]` after the double backslashes after `\end{split}`, not to add an extra pair of backslashes. The latter creates a bogus blank equation; the former does not.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @campa you can replace the separating `\\` with `\\[4ex]` does the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
{}&\int_{-T}^{T} a_n \cos{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}dt=\frac{a_nT}{n\pi}\cdot-
\sin{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}\rvert_{-T}^T=\\
%
&-\frac{a_nT}{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\sin{(n\pi)}-\sin{(-n\pi)}\rbrack=\frac{a_nT}
{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack0-0\rbrack=0
\end{split}\\[4ex]
%I'd like a white line here, separating the two equations more clearly. It needs to be exactly the size of 1 normal white space.
\begin{split}
{}&\int_{-T}^{T} b_n \sin{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)} dt=\frac{b_nT}
{n\pi}\cdot\cos{(\tfrac{n\pi}{T}t)}\rvert_{-T}^T=\\
%
&\frac{b_nT}{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\cos{(n\pi)}-\cos{(-n\pi)}\rbrack=\frac{b_nT}
{n\pi}\cdot\lbrack\cos{(n\pi)}-\cos{(n\pi)}\rbrack=0
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]